# SCCM 2012 R2 Deployment Questions

Tags: sccm-2012-r2

I'm very new to SCCM but have managed to install it from scratch, it's by far the most complex software I've ever had to install and configure. I have a few basic questions if I'm allowed to ask more than 1 in the same post. They should be straight forward answers at least:

1- Software deployment - If I deploy an application to a device collection, and then a week or 2 after the deadline when all other devices are 100% compliant, another machine is added to the device collection, will the software still attempt to roll out to the machine or do I need to do another deployment?

2- Software deployment - Sometimes when I deploy an application it takes a while to start. What is the trigger for it to check for new software and install? i.e. If I need to quickly deploy software on a machine what do I need to do to get it to detect the software and start downloading/installing it straight away. Is there a certain task I can run on the machine? (The equivalent of a "check for updates" button?)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 As long as a package is on scope it will attempt to deploy.

2 On the local machine there is a software center icon under the control panel. I always need to poke around to find it.  If you run the various policies there - notably the machine, update and application deplyment ones - it will install pending sofware and updates nearly immediately.

Comment: Thank you I'm sure this is exactly the answer I need, but can you just clarify what exactly you mean by "on scope" ?